# Is there any way to run child process on new tab instaed on same parent terminal tab?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am creating 2 child process but i want to run child process on different tab than parent tab ,but i am not getting how to do this .Please any one help me to over come this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that you are writing a C program, I don't think that this is a very good idea because if you manage doing it at all, it will tie you to a particular terminal emulator.  There surely is a better way to organize your program.

Comment: A better approach is to disconnect from the terminal and perform I/O via sockets (or files, or whatever).  Then if somebody wants to connect a terminal to the sockets, that's easy to do.

Comment: What terminal does this need to work with?  xterm doesn't have tabs, neithe does the console.